# How to install OpenCV for python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

HI! I'm trying to install opencv and use it with python, but when I compile it I get no errors but I can't import cv module from python:

```
patrick:release patrick$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

The code I used to compile it is this:

```
cd opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON
make
sudo make install
```

how can I get it working with python?

Comment: I posted a [blog post](http://sunny.in.th/2010/04/27/installing-opencv-21-on-snow-leopard.html) showing how to install OpenCV 2.1 on Snow Leopard. Maybe you can check it out.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891790/installing-opencv-for-python-on-mavericks/25021812#25021812

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found here a way to install opencv for python: http://recursive-design.com/blog/2010/12/14/face-detection-with-osx-and-python/ :)

Comment: It works the same also for Linux, not only OSX. The important step is to define [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable according to where `cv.so` is installed.

Answer (score 18):

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitos when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 2):

We can install opencv for Python for Mac OS X with home-brew.

First, install home-brew:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

You can see the details for how to install homebrew. http://brew.sh

If you don't install Python, install python(brew will install python2.7):

`brew install python`

Maybe you want install Python3: `brew install python3`

Then install opencv3 for Python3:

`brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

If you want install opencv3 for Python(Python2.7):  `brew install opencv3 --with-python`

OR install opencv2 for Python3: `brew install opencv --with-python3`

OR if you want install opencv2 for Python3: `brew install opencv --with-python3`

Finally, maybe you will **link site-packages of opencv to the site-packages of Python.**

Notes: In the follow command, `/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages` is the directory of opencv3's site-packages, `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` is the directory of Python3.5's site-packages.

Maybe you should change the two to your own OPENCV AND PYTHON `site-packages` directories.

`echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv3.pth`

Answer (score 2):

```
easy_install pip
pip install opencv-python --user
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Maybe you will use `sudo`,

and the path of installed may not be like mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (change python36 to whatever version you want)

`sudo port install opencv +avx2 +python36 +qt5 +contrib +eigen`

I got [this error](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/53427#no1) and had to apply the patch there ([download link](https://trac.macports.org/raw-attachment/ticket/53427/patch-cpp11-narrowing-error.diff))

Apply the patch with:

```
sudo patch /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp ~/Downloads/patch-cpp11-narrowing-error.diff
```

Then run `sudo port install -N opencv +avx2 +python36 +qt5 +contrib +eigen` again

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ctypes-opencv](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/) -- not sure why building and installing with `-D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON` didn't work for you (maybe it doesn't know where to install the Python wrappers in osx...?), but the ctypes wrappers should, in theory, work anyway.

Comment: the build_python instruction seems to be not working because it doesn't create the cv.pyd (it creates only cv.so). Anyway I just tried ctypes-opencv and I get this error: http://dpaste.com/221536/

Answer (score 0):

If you have you want a simple and quick install in Windows, you can download [Python(x,y)](http://python-xy.github.io). This distribution includes OpenCv. Be sure to specify that you want to install OpenCV in the installation setup, because it is not installed by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on os x currently :)

Comment: @insys I fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

When using Virtual Environment

Thanks to @user495470. Follow these steps

```
brew update
brew install -v cmake 
brew install opencv`
```

If Part 1 didn't work kindly follow Part 2 
**Part I**
Next step might work sometime, although it didn't work for me
`export PYTHONPATH="/VENV_PATH/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"`
Then check in python IDE check with `import cv` or `import cv2`
**Part 2**
Go to this path
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Copy `cv2.so` file
Paste it `/VENV_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages` here
Then check in python IDE check with `import cv` or `import cv2`
**Kindly let me know if this thing works.**