# Cannot import cv2 in python in OSX

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed OpenCV 3.1 in my Mac, cv2 is also installed through `pip install cv2`.

```
vinllen@ $ pip install cv2
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cv2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But it looks like `cv2` and `cv` cannot be used:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:05:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

I have tried almost all the solutions list online, but cannot work.

Comment: There are many questions regarding this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790501/why-cv2-so-missing-after-opencv-installed  and  http://answers.opencv.org/question/58626/opencv-with-python-on-a-mac/  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325528/how-to-install-opencv-for-python  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**I do not know what `pip install cv2` actually installs... but is surely *not* OpenCV.** `pip install cv2` actually installs [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cv2/1.0), which are some *blog distribution utilities*, not sure what it is, but it is **not** OpenCV.

---

To properly install OpenCV, check any of the links @udit043 added in the comment, or refer to any of the tutorials bellow:

Find here a tutorial on how to install OpenCV on OS X:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

You need to actually compile OpenCV from source and activate python bindings, which takes a while.

Another option is to use `brew` to get OpenCV, but doesn't neccesarilly get you the last version nor a fully optimized one:

https://web.archive.org/web/20171218032016/http://www.mobileway.net/2015/02/14/install-opencv-for-python-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks imaluengo, the url in the bottom helps me.   1.brew tap homebrew/science 2.brew install opencv 3. cp /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/   where the step 3 can solve the problem of link error lists in the blog

Comment: That site mobileway.net has been hacked

Comment: @vinllen Thanks! After following the tutorial this step is necessary: `cp  /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` since it seems that the `opencv3.pth` file that points to the `/opt/opencv3` lib does not work.

Comment: This is no longer the best answer. See below upvoted answer

Comment: `Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.`

Answer (score 137):

You can install by

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This just worked without having to go through the long and tedious tutorial from Imanol Luengo.

Comment: @frakman1 agreed! When I posted my answer OpenCV didnt have a `pip` install. As of today this is the correct way to go!

Comment: You might also want to install `opencv-contrib-python` depending on your project requirements. Check https://docs.opencv.org/master/ for a list of extra modules.

Comment: OP should choose this one as the answer. Then others won't need to navigate down the page.

Comment: this will only let you use your CPU as it does not include any of the CUDA bindings

Answer (score 5):

I used 
`conda install opencv`
and it installed fine for me.

You might want to try this if you are using Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

pip3 install opencv-python

Should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

For me installation using **conda** didn't worked.
While installing it using pip worked:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

os: macos Catalina

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that numpy, other dependency is installed prior installing OpenCV
Also if you installed using PIP then check the installed packages using

```
pip freeze
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install by

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; here's what worked for me: `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda`

If you haven't already, do the following to get conda up and running on OS X (taken from [docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html)):

1. Download [Miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html)
2. Download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)
3. Locate to the director that contains the Miniconda file and run `bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` in Terminal
4. Follow the prompts to install Anaconda
5. Run `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda`

You could also try `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` and `conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv` if step 5 doesn't work, as someone recommended when I had the same problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

pip is renamed to pip3 so please use

pip3 install opencv-python

Comment: `pip` should point to `pip3` see discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3