# python cv2 not found but installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, homebrew

I pip installed cv2 the opencv2 python lib

`pip install cv2`

I also have opencv installed on my machine using

`brew install opencv`.

it installed correctly and if I try to run it again I get

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cv2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

however when I try to import it I get an error thats it not found. To make it simple I'm gonna run python through my terminal:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>>
```

Comment: That doesn't install `opencv`, it installs [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cv2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853220/cannot-import-cv2-in-python-in-osx

Comment: Run `pip show cv2` to get information regarding the pip package

Comment: @Forge I  know I already have opencv installed on my machine. I updated my question to make that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few more steps to complete when installing `opencv` using `brew` on mac.

Create symbolic links to the compiled library

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/<opencv_version>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/<opencv_version>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

Then, updating your `PYTHONPATH` to include site-packages

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Credit goes to [jjyap](https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/)

Note that this is correct for `opencv 2` versions. For `opencv 3` there are a few other steps to complete such as building opencv together with extra modules as described here - [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib).

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem in MacOS. Tried to `ls /Library/Python` and got `ls: permission denied` therefore I had no read permission on the folder.

So I changed the permissions of the folder:

```
sudo find  ~/Library/Python -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and it worked.