# Issues while installing utilities module in python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Am trying to install utilities module for both python and anaconda environment.I have python 3 in my Mac.Here is the error I get.

```
 pip install utilities
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for utilities

Please help :(

Comment: as you're using `python3`, try `pip3 install utilities`, [pip or pip3 to install packages for Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3)

Comment: still not working @downshift

Comment: is it this package [utilities 1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utilities)? maybe it has been abandoned and the package isn't supported anymore. try `pip search utilities`, but sound likely the package isn't available any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying the ML example from [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Artificial-Intelligence-with-Python/tree/master/Chapter%2002/code), then please copy the utilities.py from chapter 2 in your python 3 in Lib directory and you will be able to use the utility module.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

`pip install data-utilities`

You can find more on the [Python Package Index - data-utilities](https://pypi.org/project/data-utilities/) website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no module named utilities in Python,I believe you have encountered importing a file called `utilities.py` by the line `import utilities`. Showing the full source code might help. Additionally, check the gitgub repo of your source code for a file called `utilities.py` and copy it to your execution folder. If you are talking about `python-utils`, check this [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/).
Python Utilities contains many standard utility modules to solve common problems. They are :

**File System** -- os, os.path, shutil

**Running External Processes** -- commands

**Exceptions**

**HTTP** -- urllib and urlparse

Check This [link](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/utilities)

If this doesn't solve your issue, try installing the [utilities-package](https://pypi.org/project/utilities-package/) using :

```
pip install utilities-package
```