# Pycharm Module Installation: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'

Tags: python, image-processing, pycharm, utilities

I am using Pycharm Virtual Environment for a project and working on windows 8.1 x64. Trying to do image processing on python and for this needed to import utilities. The package is present at this link. https://pypi.org/project/utilities/

In my code i am using these commands:

```
from utilities.utilities import Utilities as Utils
import utilities.constants as Constants
```

and when I try to do pip install utilities or try to install the package from settings, even though it is present there but it gives these errors

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

How can I install this package if I cannot use pip then how do i manually install from package. Please guide on both.

Comment: I think I found answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143332/issues-while-installing-utilities-module-in-python  The problem lies with module, I believe