# Unable to install pipenv, unable to upgrade pip's setup tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pipenv

I'm trying to set up the environment to do some Python on a new laptop. I did `brew install python3` first, then went to make sure I had pip installed with `pip --version`. The terminal said I didn't, so I did `brew install pip`.

Then I went to install pipenv with `pip install pipenv`. I got this error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-build-o6M3Ve/pipenv/.
```

Searching that, I saw people saying that pip's setup tools needed to be updated with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. When I tried that I got a really long error, which I'll post below. I'm in way over my head with this one and don't know where to start. Any and all help is appreciated.

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
```

Error:

```
[('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/9t/pk6bmgc968d_fys24blkrgc40000gn/T/pip-Rp7V_U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Comment: after you install python3 by brew, you should use `pip3` or make soft link to `pip`,(no need to install `pip` by brew) can reference to my another answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3/40832702#40832702

Comment: @CSJ Do I need to get rid of `pip`?

Comment: yes, remove it as below answer mentioned too

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Python version 3 but the pip that belongs to Python version 2. First of all, uninstall the pip that you have installed. Now you should install pip3, e.g. using `brew install pip3`. However, pip3 should have been installed along with Python 3, so first make sure that pip3 really is not already installed.