# Message "you must have pygmentize installed to use this package" while Pygments is already installed

Tags: python, package, latex, pygments

I'm try to use the `minted` package in latex to display code in latex document. From Texstudio, I get an error message "you must have pygmentize installed to use this package". However, if I type `pip3 install pygments` I get `Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.3.1)` which means that `pip3` has installed it on the machine

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you have several versions of Python installed?
What if you type "pip2 install pygments"? Have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3

Comment: Inspired by the above comment (and not digging more deeply) - "pip3 install pygments" fixed my issue.