# Make VS Code terminal match debug environment on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, environment

I'm teaching a beginners python class, the environment is Anaconda, VS Code and git (plus a few extras from a `requirements.txt`).

For the windows students this runs perfectly, however the mac students have an existing python (2.7) to contend with.

The windows students (i.e. they have a windows computer), their environment when they debug matches their console environment. However the mac students seem to be locked to their 2.7 environment.

I've tried aliasing, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425592/1835727) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377932/1835727)

```sh
alias python2='python'
alias python='python3'
alias pip2='pip'
alias pip='pip3'
```

I've modified the `.bash_profile` file

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/Users/$USER/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >>.bash_profile
```

Both of these seem to work perfectly to modify their Terminal environments, when launched externally to VS Code. Neither seem to do anything to the environment launched from [cmd]+[`].

I've also tried `conda activate base` in the terminal, which seems to have no effect on a `python --version` or a `which python`

They *can* run things using `python 3`, but that means that they need to remember that they are different to the other 2/3 of the students. It's othering for them, and more work for me!

The students are doing fine, launching things from their external terminal, but it would streamline things greatly if the environments could be as consistent as possible across the OSs.

Whilst they *are* complete beginners, they can run a shell script. They currently have one that installs pip requirements and vs code extensions.

Is there a configuration that will keep the terminal in line with the debug env?

Comment: My recommendation: [ignore python 2](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: @cglacet, that's what I want to do

Comment: Can't you just completely hide python 2? So vscode will only see the python 3 interpreter and will therefore have no other choice than picking the "right" interpreter.   How much control do you have over their environment? When you say `echo "xx" >> .bash_profile` does that mean that you expect the students to run that command?

Comment: Install the Python extension, and you can select the Python version you want to use in the bottom bar.

Comment: On a mac, it's `source activate base`, not `conda activate base`. Also, it's `python -V`, not `python --version` for some annoying reason with python. When you write ``cmd+` ``, do you mean launching an external terminal from vscode using `cmd+shift+C`? Anyway, it's possible to make that use a conda environment, but it's inconsistent. It's easier for a group to use the integrated terminal in vscode after installing the Microsoft python extension and configuring the python environment via the status bar or settings. The integrated terminal respects the conda environment.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best practice is to create Python virtual environments (personally I love using `conda` environments, especially on Mac where you stuck with unremovable old Python version). Then VSCode will **automatically** (after installing very powerful Python extension) find all your virtual environments. This way you will teach your students a good practice of handling Python zoo a.k.a. package incompatibilities. Terminal environments settings will be consistent with VSCode, without being dependent on unneeded any more aliases. Obviously, virtual environments are OS independent, so you will be more consistent and remove unnecessary confusion between different students.

The additional bonus of the virtenvs is that you can create one exactly according to your `requirements.txt` and switch from one to another with a single click (in terminal it takes two commands: `deactivate` -> `activate`).

You can read more about how to handle Python virtual environments on [VSCode site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 3):

Given the aliases are run just once and are not persistent in  `.bash_profile`, `python` targets the default interpreter rather than the expected conda `python3` interpreter.

Try to symlink conda's `python3` executable to capture the `python` namespace

```sh
ln -sf /Users/$USER/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/$USER/anaconda3/bin/python
```

This will create or update the symlink. Use the same approach for `pip` and `pip3`.

Answer (score 3):

Python in vscode let's you select which interpreter will be used to run the scripts.
It is in settings under `"python.pythonPath"`, just set it to point to the interpreter of choice.
It can be set on a project basis as well (which is how you ensure that a project that has a virtual environment will execute using that interpreter and packages), you just select **Workspace** in the settings pane and add the desired python interpreter there.