# Problem while installing OwlReady2 (Python lib) in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, owlready

I am trying to install the **owlready2** lib in Ubuntu by following the method below but I face a problem.

- I updated the system and applications
- Installed Python 3 and made it the working version (default)
- Installed pip3
- Used pip and pip3 to install the owlready2 lib

But I faced the below problem which seems to be a problem with the library package:

> error: can't copy './hermit/org/semanticweb/hermiT/hierarchy':
>   doesn't exist or not a regular file"
>
> Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_buil
>   d_root/owlready2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
>   open)(**file** ).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))"
>   install --record /tmp/pip-lq v533ik-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile f ailed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/owlready2 Storing debug log for failure in
>   /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: can you put the plain text of the output and command properly formatted? It id difficult to read the red-on-black image...

Comment: Please provide more information, the command you run, result of `which python`, `which pip` commands. Full stacktrace of error you are having.

Comment: @cccnrc did it.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I mentioned Python3 and both pip and pip3. Do you want the exact versions?

Comment: Yes, versions is good to have to. Also try to upgrade pip itself.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko pip3 version comes back as 1.5.4 (python 3.4) and Python comes back as 3.4.3!  Now I am a little bit confused myself!

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3 to get idea of what's going on

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Just a question: Do you know why I get different versions when I used python --version whereas when I type Python? Are there both Pythons available at the same time on my system?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install your package with the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install -I owlready2
```

If pip3 does not work, you also install Owlready2 manually : download the sources, then run in a terminal:

```
cd /path/to/Owlready2
python setup.py build 
python setup.py install # as root
```

Also, that would be a good ide to install pip3 and try to install your package with `pip3`, commands below:

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

Comment: The first command produced the same result. Will test the second part.

Comment: What if you run first command, but instead of pip put `pip3` ?

Comment: says "no module named pip3"

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip` and then retry `python3 -m pip install -I owlready2
`

Comment: says can't roll back pip (from python 2)

Comment: Alright, then you are trying to install something for python 3 with pip for python 2,  I guess. Install the pip3 and then use it for installing desired package.

Comment: OK. Of course, I am almost sure I did install it. However, maybe I have installed it on an another remote computer since I have access to more than one. I'll read the link you provided to see what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: I think I got the correct pip3 (1.5.4 Python3) . But seems that I'm still facing the same problem! The only thing I have not done is to install it manually.

Comment: @RFNO Managed to install it ?

Comment: No, for now I've stopped attemting to install it. I am using Blazegraph to see if the works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

It seems that the issue might lie in something that was added in version 0.14 (at the time of writing the newest version is 0.19). If the owlready2 version is newer than 0.13 then you will encounter the problem.

I have tested these Python versions - 3.7.3 (works), 3.6.8(works), 3.5.2(works until v0.13), 3.4.3(works until v0.13)

To install version v0.13 of owlready2:

```html
pip install owlready2==0.13
```