# Can't install DjangoRestFramework using pip3?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, django-rest-framework, pip

I've been trying

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
```

and I've been getting this result:

```
Collecting djangorestframework
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/djangorestframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/djangorestframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/djangorestframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/djangorestframework/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/djangorestframework/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangorestframework (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for djangorestframework
```

I'm using python3 which is why I used pip3.

**EDIT** Just for extra clarification... this ONLY happens when installing and uninstalling this package. I tested with pytz and I was allowed to install and uninstall freely.

Also pip3 search throws up the same SSL Errors then spits this up at me:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 668, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 775, in request
    headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 567, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

Comment: This looks like a network issue. Are you able to install other packages using `pip3`? Which python distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.2

Comment: I am also able to install other packages. I just uninstalled and reinstalled pytz to test

Comment: Python 3.6.8 is the python version, but how did you install it? Through `apt`, by downloading it from https://www.python.org/ or do you have `anaconda`...?

Comment: just through apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the requirements for [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements).

> ### **Requirements**
>
> REST framework requires the following:
>
> Python (3.5, 3.6, 3.7) Django (1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2)
>
> We highly
>   recommend and only officially support the latest patch release of each
>   Python and Django series.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.2. So based on this I think it should still work?

Comment: It seems like ssl issue and you are not able to communicate with PyPi. Try upgrading your pip with :
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Comment: I had the same issue when I was setting up my project on Mac. Well, I had resolved this issue following this: https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko/issues/238#issuecomment-381177120

Comment: I tried this but now I only have pip 19.3.1 and no pip3. I need pip3 for using this with python3 dont I?

Comment: Arn't you using venv created via python3. if you are in a Python3 venv, pip will operate on the Python3 environment. Have a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3

Comment: Not using a venv. Running a virtual machine just for this project so figured I'd skip that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install requirements with django==2.2. Then if you need Django 3 and above you then install it after you install all other requirements. Although you going to see the dependency errors it will work fine.