# How can I fix this issue with SublimeLinter?

Tags: sublimetext3, flake8, sublimelinter

I hope it is ok to ask this even though it is not specifically a programming question. I installed the `SublimeLinter` and `SublimeLinter-flake8` packages in Sublime Text 3.
I did `pip install flake8` and restarted but the console shows the following message:

> SublimeLinter: WARNING: cannot locate 'flake8'. Fill in the 'python' or 'executable' setting.
>   WARNING:SublimeLinter.lint.base_linter.python_linter:cannot locate 'flake8'.Fill in the 'python' or 'executable' setting

I suspect it may have to do with setting a path in the user settings, but I am not sure how to go about it. 
As you may see I am a relative newbie.
Thanks.

Comment: [This should help you](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/1462)

Comment: @0stone0 feel free to post an answer. That thread is kind of convoluted, so a simple, straightforward explanation of the fix would be appropriate here. Be sure to reference the original link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please ensure you've followed these steps:

1. Install SublimeText packages ([help](https://packagecontrol.io/installation))

   - SublimeLinter
   - SublimeLinter-flake8
2. Install [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) (use `pip`, or `pip3` if you have multiple python versions)

   - `pip3 install flake8`
3. Configure `flake8` settings

   1. Open Sublime Text
   2. Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime Linter -> Settings
   3. Set the path to the desired python version:

<sub>Notice: Custom settings needs to be on the right(user) side!</sub>

```
{
    "linters": {
        "flake8": {
            "executable": [ "python3", "-m", "flake8" ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Restart** Sublime to enable the changes

[image]

<sub>Not sure about `pip` or `pip3`? Please take a look at [pip or pip3 to install packages for Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3)</sub>

Comment: You can also put this in your .sublime-project file:
`{"settings": {"SublimeLinter.linters.flake8.executable": ["python", "-m", "flake8"]}}`