# can't use opencv-python without xcode (MAC os)?

Tags: python, opencv

I had Xcode installed before, but my mac has a really small SSD so I figured I delete it.

I can still use the command:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

It runs and I get :

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.5.2.54)
```

But when I try to import it I get an error:

```
no module named cv2
```

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62160887/2836621

Comment: to be specific: are you actually running python3, or some other python?

Comment: I'm running python3

Comment: Are you sure?  If you do `python -V`, does it confirm that?

Comment: Yes, i use 3.8.7