# Can't install OpenCV python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

When I execute this command:

`pip3 install opencv-python`

I get the following error:

```
  Installing build dependencies ... error                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-z4c_sn6u/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"''       cwd: None
  Complete output (22 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading setuptools-49.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (803 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading wheel-0.35.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
  Collecting scikit-build
    Using cached scikit_build-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
  Collecting cmake
    Using cached cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz (28 kB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-95tsmt_u/cmake/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-95tsmt_u/cmake/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-95tsmt_u/cmake/pip-egg-info
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-95tsmt_u/cmake/
      Complete output (5 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-95tsmt_u/cmake/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
          from skbuild import setup
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-z4c_sn6u/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Same when I tried to install ecapture, I am using the latest python version

Comment: Have you tried to update all your packages:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip

Comment: Not sure this might be related, but have you tried `pip` instead of `pip3`. If not, you could try getting the wheel file directly from the [website](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and installing it.

Comment: Hmm, will try it.

Comment: Nope, I need only pip3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to upgrade your pip with

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then run the

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 9):

Installation and Usage guide on pypi web site says

## Pip install fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'?

Since opencv-python version 4.3.0.*, manylinux1 wheels were replaced by manylinux2014 wheels. If your pip is too old, it will try to use the new source distribution introduced in 4.3.0.38 to manually build OpenCV because it does not know how to install manylinux2014 wheels. However, source build will also fail because of too old pip because it does not understand build dependencies in pyproject.toml. To use the new manylinux2014 pre-built wheels (or to build from source), your pip version must be >= 19.3.
Please upgrade pip with
`pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Didn't help, pip3 install --upgrade pip it's important for me to use pip3

Comment: @DmirtyTrecenko What version of pip3 do you use? Show output of that command:
pip3 --version   
Also check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832677/11278441

Comment: pip 20.0.2 from use/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: I tested this on pip 20.2.2 using pip3 and it works. Try to update pip to 20.2.2 version using this command:  pip3 install --upgrade pip

Comment: Okay, now it writes Successfully installed pip 20.2.2 but command --version outputs old version

Comment: Magic! You might probably checked pip version not pip3, or idk.

Comment: ```root@kali:/# pip3 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pip-20.2.2
root@kali:/# pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)```

Comment: It's very likely that `pip` cannot be easily upgraded / upgrade fails silently with that default upgrade command if it has been originally installed via your Linux distribution repositories (the system repository maintainers should keep `pip` up-to-date but looks like many distros ship with 2,5+ year or even 5+ year old `pip` version). My recommendation would be to use `virtualenv` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) whenever possible. Then the most recent versions of Python tooling are always available / easily upgradeable.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing this similar situation:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y vim curl iputils-ping python3-dev python3-pip libsm6 
libxext6 libxrender-dev python3.6
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
...
```

requirements.txt:

```
...
opencv-python
...
```

Upon running `docker-compose up &`, I was receiving this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/tmp/pip-build-acog3xol/opencv-python/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
     import skbuild
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
```

I tried the suggested solutions of upgrading `pip3` but was getting the same problem.

What worked for me was fixing the `opencv-python` version in `requirements.txt`. Previously, it was pulling version `4.4.0.40`. I instead changed `requirements.txt` to:

```
...
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
...
```

Comment: Had the same experience and downgrading to v4.2.0.34 worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the opencv-python PyPi page they will give troubleshooting tips for common errors. See [opencv-python 4.4.0.40](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

The error you're encountering is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
```

The fix for this is listed under the FAQ as follows:

---

**Q: Pip install fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'?`**

Since `opencv-python` version 4.3.0.*, `manylinux1` wheels were replaced by `manylinux2014` wheels. If your pip is too old, it will try to use the new source distribution introduced in 4.3.0.38 to manually build OpenCV because it does not know how to install `manylinux2014` wheels. However, source build will also fail because of too old pip because it does not understand build dependencies in `pyproject.toml`. To use the new `manylinux2014` pre-built wheels (or to build from source), your `pip` version must be >= 19.3. Please upgrade `pip` with `pip install --upgrade pip`.

**TLDR**:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: ```pip3 install --upgrade pip ``` didn't help

Comment: It's important to use pip3

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

pip3 install cmake --user

pip3 install --upgrade pip --user

pip3 install opencv-python --user

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.8 was not working for me too. Now installing using Python 3.7, and it looks ok though still in progress:

```
python3.7 -m pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.38
```

Comment: didn't work for me, sadly. same error. EDIT: upgrading pip3 and then this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python 3.7.6 this is the most stable version. there are many things that don't install on 3.8.

Comment: How can I downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install sbuild via pip. you can follow the below command.
It worked on my pc.

```sh
python3 -m pip install scikit-build
```

Best of Luck for you.