# How to fix syntax error (Missing parentheses in call to 'print') in pip install

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I wanted to install one dependency ("cycle" to be exact) using "pip install". But I've came along some syntax errors

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("cycle o
nly supports Python 2.7 and higher")?
```

I've tried downloading the package manually and trying to install it again, but still, the same error.  I don't know many stuff about python to be honest, so... yeah.

Comment: It seems the package was written for Python 2 and you are using Python 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832533/pip-or-pip3-to-install-packages-for-python-3

Comment: then how I can "fix" it? It's needed for one program.

Comment: So i need to change every "print "something"" to "print("something")". Gotcha