# How do I solve the there is no Crypto package error in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto, des

I am having an error in my Python code, basically I need to import the package Crypto and I have tried to download it, it says that the package crypto has been installed then keeps showing the same error. I have tried to rename the package from crypto to Crypto but it shows again the same error. Can you please help me how to solve this error or is there any alternative package. Thank you

I tried to import DES  and RSA from the cryto library but I can not properly download the package Crypto.

edit: I tried to install from the terminal: pip install Crypto also directly proposed by intelliJ, the code that i'm trying is

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.PublicKey import  RSA
```

Comment: Please show us how you installed the package, the code you are using to import it, and the exact error that is generated

Comment: It's explained in the post, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

The package you shall install is called `pycryptodome`, so try installing

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

It is somehow dependent on system libraries so it might evantually get broken. To fix this was created `pycryptodomex` library that has everything bundled in, which you install using

```
pip install pycryptodomex
```

But then instead of your original code you need to use

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import DES
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import  RSA
```

Comment: Depending on the system you may have to use `pip3` for `python3`, `pip` is a softlink [which *should* point to the correct version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40832533/589259).