# No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, opencv

After spending hours trying out others' suggestions, I still can't get OpenCV to work. I'd like to build a Python script that checks an image's/PDF's color at a certain area (it's for a printing company to verify that documents have a 0.5mm white border, as this is their machine's preferred format). That said, I'm planning on using OpenCV's color detection capabilities to set an RGB tolerance for a document's contours.

I've tried installing OpenCV with `brew`, `brew install homebrew/science/`, `sudo pip`, `sudo pip3`, `pip` and `pip3`, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

What confuses me most is that it seems I've successfully installed OpenCV when I enter `pkg-config opencv --cflags` in terminal:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/include
```

Is the wrapper no longer supporter for Python 3.6? If so, where could I get a similar package?

Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

lst_intensites = [(255, 255, 255)]

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cimg = np.zeros_like(img)
    cv2.drawContours(cimg, contours, i, color=255, thickness=-1)

    pts = np.where(cimg == 255)
    lst_intensities.append(img[pts[0], pts[1]])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34853347/4098013

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well I was also facing the same issue today but I finally installed it in Anaconda and it's working fine:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
```

source:[Opencv Installation](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thanks! Conda did the trick after some troubleshooting. Here's what ended up solving the problem: `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda`

Comment: I ran `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` once and it did not work. Then I did various things, and ran this command again, now it worked. For anyone else stumble upon this, I also had a ROS installation that will mess up the `sys.path` and I have to delete it from `sys.path` before being able to read the correct opencv.

Answer (score 26):

On Windows, you can install with pip:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: pip isn't specific to windows. That will work on Linux and Mac as well.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu, you can install the `opencv` depends like:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

or install it with pip ( python package management tools ):

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Refer to similar questions [OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2).

Answer (score 0):

For windows, this will work

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

then install opencv,

```
pip install opencv-python
```